# How to use dynamic strings with flutter_localizations

Tags: flutter, localization, flutter-dependencies, flutter-localizations

I use these two classes for localization in flutter
following this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/multi-language-support-in-flutter-a12de708f833) setup.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

abstract class Languages {
  final String? extra;

  Languages({this.extra});
  static Languages? of(BuildContext context, {String? extra}) {
    return Localizations.of<Languages>(context, Languages);
  }
String get text199;
}
```

and this LanguageEn:

```
import 'languages.dart';

class LanguageEn extends Languages
{
  LanguageEn({String? extra}) : super(extra: extra);
  @override
String get text199 => "Update data($extra)";
}
```

when I pass this extra parameter I get null `"Update data(null)"` in whatever language I'm in

`Languages.of(context,extra: "$activeID")!.text199),`

but when I directly select a language class and do this it works and I get the number and not null `"Update data(4)"`

`LanguageEn(extra: "$activeID").text199),`

how to pass dynamic strings with this package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by replacing that Language class with the [following](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/135875):

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

abstract class Languages {
    String? extra;

  Languages({this.extra});
  static Languages? of(BuildContext context, {String? extra}) {
    final Languages? instance = Localizations.of<Languages>(context, Languages);
    if (instance != null) {
      instance.extra = extra; // Assign the extra parameter to the instance.
    }
    return instance;
  }

  String get text199;
  }
```